# nginx breaks when adding additional server block

Tags: configuration, nginx

I have a working nginx configuration, however when I add an additional server{} block, one of the other server blocks breaks.

The additional server block I am adding is below:

```
server {
    listen 172.30.170.152:80;
    server_name example.com;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|exe|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|avi|html|mov|zip)$ {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        expires 90d;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        expires 90d;

    }

    location ~ /\.git {
        rewrite .* / permanent;
    }


 }
```

There are several other identical server blocks (other than server_name) in use within this configuration, none of which cause this issue.

The only thing special about the server {} block that breaks, is the large number of sever_names within it - I've not counted it (too many) - but a figure I've pulled out of the ether is about 170.

Other things that might help:

- There are 20 server {} blocks before adding this additional one
- nginx version: nginx/1.0.15
- CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the number of `server_name`s? What is the log output of nginx when trying to start?

Comment: I removed a few server_name s and had the same issue.
A couple of conflicting server_names were output to the error.log and nothing was output to access.log - I don't know of any other nginx log files

Comment: Why do you have conflicting names?

Comment: Because there were a couple of duplicates within the server_name block - which I have since removed. However it doesn't cause any difference in behaviour of nginx